# not able to save data after running code

Tags: vba, excel

When I went home yesterday, my code was working just fine.  I get to work today and now every time I run the code, Excel starts acting funky.  It is not saving the workbook, returning a msgbox "document not saved".  When I turned my computer on (should have been sleeping), it completely started from an improper shutdown mode.  I am not sure if this is what is causing the issue.  I have tried using the code into a completely different workbook and still have the same issues.  Also, after I run the code, if I click on the "file" tab, nothing is shown.  Anyone have any insight to the issue?  Thanks.

I am pretty sure the code is fine, but here it is.

```
Sub TripLines()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Call AddGMTDateTimeStampsColumns
  Call ComputeGMTDateTimeStamps
  Call DeleteNonStampColumns
  Call SplitLegStamp
  Call CreateLegStamp
  Call DeleteNonLegStampColumns
  Call BuildLines
  Call FindLastLeg
  Call LineLegCount
  Call TrimDownTripLines  

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub TrimDownTripLines()
  Dim Z As Integer

  Z = Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row

  On Error Resume Next  
  'Trim down Lines  
  Sheets("DataImport").Range = Range(Cells(1, 1), (Cells(Z, 16384)))
  Sheets("DataImport").Sort.SortFields.Clear
  Sheets("DataImport").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        Cells(1, 1), (Cells(Z, 1))), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
  Sheets("DataImport").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        Cells(1, 2), (Cells(Z, 2))), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
  With Sheets("DataImport").Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 1), (Cells(Z, 16384)))
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
  End With
  Sheets("DataImport").Activate

  Call RemoveDuplicateLines  
End Sub


Sub LineLegCount()    
  Dim Z As Long
  Dim LC As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Trip As Range

  Z = Sheets("DataImport").Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row

  On Error Resume Next
  For i = 2 To Z
    Set Trip = Range(Cells(i, 3), (Cells(i, 3).End(xlToRight)))
    LC = Trip.Count
    Sheets("DataImport").Cells(i, 2) = LC
  Next i  
End Sub


Sub FindLastLeg()
  Dim LL As String
  Dim i As Long

  Columns(1).Select
  'Range("A460").Activate
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

  Cells(1, 1) = "Last Leg Stamp"
  Cells(1, 2) = "Line Leg Count"    

  Z = Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row

  For i = 2 To Z
    LL = Cells(i, 3).End(xlToRight)
    Sheets("DataImport").Cells(i, 1) = LL
  Next i
End Sub


Sub FilterByFleet()
  UF_FleetSelect.Show
End Sub

Sub BuildLines()
'strings together segments into trip

  Dim i As Long
  Dim Z As Long
  Dim T As Long
  Dim LegTable As Range
  Dim y As String
  Dim b As String
  Dim MyTimer As Double

  'ThisWorkbook.Save
  DoEvents

  Range(Cells(1, 3), (Cells(1048576, 16384))).Clear
  Set LegTable = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
  Z = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
  For i = 2 To Z
    MyTimer = Timer
    Do
    Loop While Timer - MyTimer < 0.03
    Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of " & Z & " " & Format(i / Z, "Percent")

    On Error Resume Next

    y = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 2), LegTable, 2, False)
    If y = "" Then
      GoTo NextI
    Else
      Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = y    
      Do Until WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 2).End(xlToRight), LegTable, 1, False) = False
        b = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 2).End(xlToRight), LegTable, 2, False)
        If b = "" Then
          GoTo NextI
        Else:
          Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = b
        End If
        b = ""
      Loop
NextI: 
    End If

    b = ""
    y = ""
  Next i

  Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub


Sub DeleteNonLegStampColumns()   
  Dim DelColumns As Range

  With Sheets("DataImport")
    Set DelColumns = Range(Columns(1), Columns(12))
  End With

  DelColumns.Delete

  Range(Columns(1), Columns(2)).Select
  Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Cells(1, 1) = "Incoming Leg Stamp"
  Cells(1, 2) = "Outgoing Leg Stamp"

End Sub

Sub CreateLegStamp()
  Dim InBndLegStamp As String
  Dim OutBndLegStamp As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Z As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  Z = Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row

  ' Inbound Dept GMT Date/Time Stamp
  For i = 2 To Z
    InBndLegStamp = (Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 2) & " " & Cells(i, 3) & _
                    " " & Cells(i, 4) & " " & Cells(i, 5) & " " & Cells(i, 6))
    Cells(i, 13).Value = InBndLegStamp

    OutBndLegStamp = (Cells(i, 7) & " " & Cells(i, 8) & " " & Cells(i, 9) & _
                     " " & Cells(i, 10) & " " & Cells(i, 11) & " " & Cells(i, 6))
    Cells(i, 14).Value = OutBndLegStamp
  Next i

End Sub


Sub SplitLegStamp()  
  Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(2, 18)) = Split(Cells(2, 13), " ")  
End Sub


Sub DeleteNonStampColumns()
  Dim DelColumns As Range

  With Sheets("DataImport")
    Set DelColumns = Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(5), .Columns(7), .Columns(8), .Columns(11), .Columns(12), .Columns(16), .Columns(17), .Columns(18))
  End With

  DelColumns.Delete

End Sub

Sub AddGMTDateTimeStampsColumns()
'insert columns for time stamps

  'Inbound Dept GMT Date/Time Stamp Column
  Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(1, 6)).EntireColumn.Insert
  Cells(1, 6) = "Inbound Dept GMT Date/Time"

  'Inbound Arrival GMT Date/Time Stamp Column
  Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(1, 9)).EntireColumn.Insert
  Cells(1, 9) = "Inbound Arvl GMT Date/Time"

  'Outbound Dept GMT Date/Time Stamp Column
  Range(Cells(1, 19), Cells(1, 19)).EntireColumn.Insert
  Cells(1, 19) = "Outbound Dept GMT Date/Time"

  'Outbound Arvl GMT Date/Time Stamp Column
  Range(Cells(1, 20), Cells(1, 20)).EntireColumn.Insert
  Cells(1, 20) = "Outbound Arvl GMT Date/Time"

End Sub

Sub ComputeGMTDateTimeStamps()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Z As Long
  Dim IDDate As Date

  'On Error Resume Next
  Z = Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row

  ' Inbound Dept GMT Date/Time Stamp
  For i = 2 To Z
    IDDate = CDate(Cells(i, 1) + Cells(i, 5))
    Cells(i, 6).Value = IDDate
  Next i

  Set Column6 = Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(2, 6).End(xlDown))

  Column6.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy hh:mm"


  ' Inbound Arival GMT Date/Time Stamp
  For i = 2 To Z
    IDDate = CDate(Cells(i, 6) + Cells(i, 8))
    Cells(i, 9).Value = IDDate
  Next i

  Set Column9 = Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(2, 9).End(xlDown))

  Column9.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy hh:mm"

  ' Outbound Dept GMT Date/Time Stamp
  For i = 2 To Z
    IDDate = CDate(Cells(i, 9) + Cells(i, 12))
    Cells(i, 19).Value = IDDate
  Next i

  Set Column19 = Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(2, 19).End(xlDown))

  Column19.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy hh:mm"

  ' Outbound Arvl GMT Date/Time Stamp
  For i = 2 To Z
    IDDate = CDate(Cells(i, 19) + Cells(i, 18))
    Cells(i, 20).Value = IDDate
  Next i

  Set Column20 = Range(Cells(2, 20), Cells(2, 20).End(xlDown))

  Column20.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy hh:mm"

End Sub
```

Module:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateLines()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim x As Double
  Dim C As Double   
  Dim Z As Integer

  Z = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row

  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))

  x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
  C = x + 3

  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), (Cells(Z, C))).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Check to see if you have outstanding `excel.exe` processes running in the background.  I'm betting that your lack of calling `.Close` and `.Exit` methods on the `Application` has an open handle on the existing file.

Comment: I am only showing the one excel.exe process running, but I am showing 70% of my memory being used.  Where should I put the .close or .exit code?

Comment: Ok, so I have determined that my   'Application.ScreenUpdating = True' was causing the issue with not being able to see the "File" tab.  Any recommendations on fixing this issue?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update!!  So when I created the new workbook, and pasted the code from Notepad, I still ran into the same problem.  I was finally able to troubleshoot the issue and discovered that if I went back and forth on the `application.screenupdating` status, it would cause the issues.  Once I trimmed it down to just going through the `false/true` statements once, that got rid of my issue completely.   Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Copy the code into notepad
2. Delete the module
3. Create a new module
4. Copy the code from notepad and paste into new module

Sometimes the modules can get corrupted, especially if your system has an improper shut down or reboot.  If this does not work, you may need to reinstall office.

There is nothing wrong with your code itself.

Comment: It worked, but I had to copy the code into a new workbook.  Fortunately, it was an easy transfer data wise.  Thanks

Comment: @MichaelByars YW.  If you ever see Excel behaving in a strange manner again, try this first.  It works almost all of the time.  If it doesn't, Excel itself is corrupt.